# Windows workflow, TrackingParticipant and Idle vs Unloaded

Tags: workflow-foundation-4, workflow-foundation, workflowservice

I am using windows workflow service and have a need to know when a workflow instance is Idle.  Using http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Windows-Workflow-b9d5ccb7 as a resource, I have created a TrackingParticipant and am being "notified" when certain states occurs, e.g. Idle, Completed, Persisted, Resumed, Unloaded, Deleted, etc.

What I expected was that, only when the workflow instance is finished processing the current activities, that the state goes to Idle.  However, it seems to go to Idle even if there is more processing for the workflow instance to perform.  For example, I might see consecutive "Idle" states for the same workflow instance.  As such, the "Idle" state is not very helpful for me in determining when the workflow instance is no longer processing any activities.

The "Unloaded" state, however, appears to give me what I want. The "Unloaed" state (as far as I can tell) only occurs when the workflow instance has no other activities to perform.

So my question is: Is it safe to rely on the "Unloaded" state to determine if the workflow instance is no longer processing any activities or is there some other technique I should use?

Thanks for your help,
Eric

Comment: The instance will enter "Idle" state if it created a bookmark and waiting it to resume. When timeToUnload expires, the instance will enter "Unload" state and completely destroyed the instance from memory. What do you mean no longer processing any activities? What do you want to achieve?

Comment: The workflow may have multiple "threads", where each "thread" will eventually become Idle.  I don't want to know when each individual "thread" becomes Idle, but rather when all of the "threads" have become idle.  Does that make sense?

Comment: You can check if all instances have bookmark from the persistence store.

Comment: Does it solve your problem?

Comment: Checking all instances sounds brittle to me for two reasons.  One, I don't know in advance how many instances there will be (there's a dynamic nature to the workflows) and two, I think it would require querying the workflow database (which I'd prefer not to do).  But let me know if I am misunderstanding your recommendation.  What I am currently doing (checking for Unload) is working for me.  I would like to confirm that it's a safe mechanism to rely on.